# Какой http-заголовок и сообщение следует выводить при ошибке подключения к MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

PHP ошибки у меня скрыты в `.htaccess` - `php_flag display_errors off`.

Answer (score 0):

В [общепринятых статусах](https://httpstatuses.com/) `http-`ответов нет ничего конкретно про ошибки, связанные с базами данных. Так что каноничным будет ответ `503 Service Unavailable`. По крайней мере, именно такой статус стоит передавать клиенту (браузеру, роботу, прочее) в `http-`заголовках.

Но при этом никто не мешает вам в случае ошибки с базой данных уже для пользователя, в теле `http-`ответа конкретизировать, с чем именно связана такая ошибка. Именно ему, а не браузеру или же какому-либо другому клиенту в программном понимании этого термина, будет интересна информация об этом.

Comment: А почему не 500?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю написанное в документации про эти коды, ошибка 500 - это ошибка сервера, а не сервиса. Ваше приложение - сервис. Сервер - это то, что позволяет получить к нему доступ, то есть как минимум веб-сервер, а как максимум - железка.

Comment: А какую ошибку надо возвращать если просто хочется сказать "иди отсюда"?

Comment: Может быть 400-ю?

Comment: @Khipster, нет, про работу сервера ошибки из пятой сотни. Из четвертой - про то, что связано с клиентом.

Comment: Я имею ввиду серверу не понравился запрос пользователя. Т.е. клиент прислал некорректный запрос.

Comment: @Khipster тогда вы можете отдать действительно какой-либо из 4хх ответов, который наиболее точно отразит суть происходящего. Но проблема в том, что в вопросе вы указали совершенно иное поведение сервера, о нем я вам и отвечаю.